# Como agregar contenido externo desde javascript hasta un archivo json ya existente?

Tags: javascript, json

Hola estoy empezando y tengo una duda que no puedo resolver, quiero que al dar click en el boton de guardar, los datos en los input queden guardados guardados en una variable para luego convertirla en json y luego agregarla al archivo ya existente, pero nada funciona.

```
   El documento json
    {
      "usuario":
        [
          { "nombre":"Ernesto" },
          { "nombre":"Anna" } 
        ]
    }
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese nombre">
  <button>guardar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: ¿estás usando algún framework js?

Comment: Desde navegador no se pueden modificar archivos si no me equivoco. Debería hacerse en el servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Este ejemplo guarda los nombres en una variable JSON.

```js
      const json = {
        usuario: []
      };
      function saveData() {
        const name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        json.usuario.push(name);
        console.log(json);
      }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Guardar input</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre" />
    <button onClick="saveData()">Guardar</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok, y como puedo hacer para esa variable creada agregarla al archivo json externo?

Comment: mi ideal es que quede algo tipo

Comment: { "usuarios": [ {"nombre": "Ernesto"}, {"nombre": "Anna"}, {"nombre": "NombrePRUEBAS"}  ] }